# how to block websites(facebook) with webmin on ubuntu 14.04 Desktop

Tags: networking, server, proxy

First, I have installed webmin and squid proxy ..

I've added a second setting on the menu
Squid Proxy server > Access Control > Access Control list > then I choose
New ACL with an option to create Web Server Hostname

I am content with the name ACL facebook and Domains I am content with .facebook.com > save

The third I've changed the access facebook in proxy restrictions

Squid Proxy server > Access Control > Proxy Restrictions
of the permit be denied it.

then apply Changes

and i tried restart the squid, but is not running..
how to overcome them?

Comment: you want to block "facebook" on ubuntu

Comment: yes, I want to block the website facebook

Comment: block his website via webmin, webmin install and I have how?

Comment: Sorry I don't know using webmin, I know but other way

Comment: refer [here](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu/) and also [this](http://aisyahtulis.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-set-proxy-to-block-website-using.html) may helpful.The second link not about Ubuntu but read totally you will get idea!

Comment: yes I've done in the tutorial that you give but I have not been well understood and do not yet know how to block websites, you may be more helpful?

Comment: finally [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) is very simple way!......and read the first section, then skip the windows explanations and scroll straight down to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, it also helps and successful but, how can I set in all PC users on a network?
whether it should be selected one by one?